# lyx, "add converter" option Disabled

Tags: lyx

I want to restore showing previews of pictures in LyX. I have found that it is necessary to have a PDF -> PNG converter defined in preferences. Currently there is no such converter, and "add" button is disabler. Why?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first change the "From format" or the "To format" and then the "Add" button will become enabled. It's not intuitive.